# Error reading value from cookie

Tags: php, database, cookies

I made a script using a cookie that has a token. Its job is to let me know if the user is logged in or not but I don't know why it always returns false. I checked my database and every time I log in a new record is created but my PHP file always returns `false`. I am using local server *easy php*. The first token dies in 7 days. The second one dies in 3 days .

```
<?php
include('./classes/DB.php');

function isloggedIn(){

    if(isset($_cookie['SNID'])){
        if(DB::query('SELECT user_id FROM login_tokens WHERE token:=token', array(':token'=>sha1($_cookie['SNID'])))){
            $userid = DB::query('SELECT user_id FROM login_tokens WHERE token:=token', array(':token'=>sha1($_cookie['SNID'])))[0]['user_id'];

            if(isset($_cookie['SNID_2'])){

            return $userid;
            }else{
                $cstrong = True;
                $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
                DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES(null, :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$userid));
                DB:query('DELETE FROM login_tokens WHERE token:=token', array(':token'=>sha1($_cookie['SNID'])));

                setcookie("SNID", $token, time()+60*60*24*7, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
                setcookie("SNID_2", $token, time()+60*60*24*3, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);

                return $userid;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (isloggedIn()){
    echo 'logged in ';
    echo isloggedIn();

    }else{
        echo 'not logged in ';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the superglobal variable  [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php). And your example uses `$_cookie`.   Variable names are case-sensitive so those are different variables.

> $_COOKIE is one of the [Predefined Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) in PHP.

Second, you can check your cookies in a browser tab `Applications` `Cookie`. In that tab look for the value corresponding to key `SNID`

Comment: i got a new error ;Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':=token' at line 1' in C:\Users\Desktop\socialnetwork\classes\DB.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C\socialnetwork\classes\DB.php(11): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\socialnetwork\index.php(7): DB::query('SELECT user_id ...', Array) #2 C:\socialnetwork\index.php(29): isloggedIn() #3 {main} thrown in C:\Desktopclasses\DB.php on line 11

Comment: you have token:=token you need write token=:token

Comment: lol how didn't i see that :p  sorry for wasting your time XD thank you man.

Comment: in `else` you have some `DB:query('DELETE FROM login_tokens WHERE token:=token'` :)